# Difference between git ls-remote and git ls-remote origin

Tags: git

What is the difference between running `git ls-remote` and `git ls-remote origin`?  It appears `git ls-remote` outputs the SHA1 IDs of each branch and tag of the original repository.  Since the original repo is by default titled origin, it appears that these two commands yield the same output.  Is this correct?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct. Because your remote is called `origin` there's no difference between the two commands.

To see all your git remotes, run `git remote -v`.

On the other hand, if your remote was called `foobar` then `git ls-remote origin` would give you this error:

```
$ git ls-remote origin
fatal: 'origin' does not appear to be a git repository
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

Comment: I think there can be difference. `git ls-remote origin --heads . dev` gives a different output than `git ls-remote --heads . dev`. At least if you do not have a local branch `dev`. To me it seems like `ls-remote origin` uses your network to check the *remote*, but `ls-remote` does not list 'dev', if you use the `--heads` flag.

Answer (score 8):

Although [the `git ls-remote` manual page](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-ls-remote.html) fails to mention this, the default argument computation here is the same as that for [`git fetch`, whose documentation is more explicit](https://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-fetch.html):

> When no remote is specified, by default the `origin` remote will be used, unless there’s an upstream branch configured for the current branch.

What this means is that if you have multiple remotes defined (e.g., `origin` and `second`) and you are on branch `B` with `branch.B.remote` set to `second`, running `git ls-remote` without any arguments is now equivalent to running `git ls-remote second`.  If you are on a more typical branch, with `branch.branch.remote` set to `origin` or not set at all, running `git ls-remote` without specifying a particular remote is equivalent to running `git ls-remote origin`.